# $\triangle{ABC},\triangle{A'B'C'}$ are acute triangles. If $\sin(2B')(\cos(2C)-\cos(2C'))+\sin(2C')(\cos(2B)-\cos(2B'))=0$, then $C=C',B=B'$.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$\triangle{ABC},\triangle{A'B'C'}$ are acute triangles. If $$\sin(2B')(\cos(2C)-\cos(2C'))+\sin(2C')(\cos(2B)-\cos(2B'))=0,$$ then $C=C',B=B'$.

I intend to show that: In acute triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'B'C'$, if $$\frac{\sin(2A)}{\sin(2A')}=\frac{\sin(2B)}{\sin(2B')}=\frac{\sin( 2C)}{\sin(2C')},$$ then $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'.$

Now I come to the equation:
$$\sin(2B')\times (\cos(2C)-\cos(2C'))+\sin( 2C')\times (\cos(2B)-\cos( 2B'))=0.$$

I think it's near to the answer, for $\cos(2C)-\cos(2C')=0$.
But I can't pass the circumstance that

$$\cos(2C)-\cos(2C')<0,\; \cos(2B)-cos(2B')>0.$$

How to continue my work?

Comment: Use, for example, `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.

Comment: You assume similarity - why?